# How do I select nodes based on a date range in xpath?

Tags: c#, .net, xpath

My XML:  http://www.lakelandcollege.ca/rustlers/all-news.xml

I was selecting a year's worth of item nodes using this code:

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.Load(Server.MapPath("/rustlers/all-news.xml"));
DataListArchive.DataSource = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("/items/item[contains(date,'2011')]");
DataListArchive.DataBind();
```

But now I need to select item nodes where the date is btw 01-Apr-2011 and 31-Mar-2012.  How do i convert the date in the XML to a real date value and compare it to a range?

I would love something like:

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.Load(Server.MapPath("/rustlers/all-news.xml"));
DataListArchive.DataSource = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("/items/item[date between '01-APR-2011' and '31-MAR-2012']");
DataListArchive.DataBind();
```

Comment: This cannot be done with a single XPath 1.0 expression. Are you interested in an XSLT 1.0 or XSLT 2.0 solution?

Comment: Do you mean between Mar 1 and April 30?

Comment: I should have been more specific.  I want to bring back item nodes where the date is btw 01-Apr-2011 and 31-Mar-2012.

Yes I am interested in an XSLT 1.0 or 2.0 solution.

Comment: Question edited to be more specific regarding dates.

Comment: Question edited to show the c# code snippet i'm using

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no general way to convert string to date nor to manipulate dates in XPath 1.0 - for your specific case (checking if a date is in March or April of a specific year):

```
/items/item[(contains(date,'April') or contains(date,'March')) and contains(date,'2010')]
```

*** UPDATE ***

Having seen the code I'd say that the easiest way is to use an XPath to get all `item` elements and then do the filtering using C# - i.e. get the value of the `date` sub-element, convert it to a date-time using `DateTime.Parse` and then do the comparison in C# code.

It is possible to add extension functions to the .NET XPath to do what you need (see [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms950806.aspx)), but it is quite complex and probably not worth the effort in this case.

Comment: I've updated my question to be more specific in regards to the dates.  Also is there Xpath 2.0?

Comment: Yes, there is XPath (and XSLT) 2.0, but the standard .NET libraries implement only the 1.0 standards - to use 2.0 you need to use a third-party library like Saxon.

Comment: Buh.  Should I use LINQ or something?  What's the elegant way to do this without a 3rd party library?

Comment: As I wrote in my answer: do the filtering in C#

Comment: I guess you're right.  I was overly excited about short the xpath code was, I think i got carried away.  I'll fart around with linq for an hour or so and if i can't do it i'll just do it the old fashioned way, like you suggested.  thx for your help!!

Comment: Ended up getting frustrated with linq and just manually iterated through the nodelist and picked out the ones i wanted.