# Can't retrieve data with xpath

Tags: c#, xpath

I have this xml :

```
 <TimePeriodDataSet xmlns="Dummy datas">
   <TimePeriods>
     <WPRD_UID>Dummy datas</WPRD_UID>
     <WPRD_START_DATE>2013-09-19T00:00:00+02:00</WPRD_START_DATE>
     <WPRD_FINISH_DATE>Dummy datas</WPRD_FINISH_DATE>
     <WPRD_NAME>Dummy datas</WPRD_NAME>
     <WPRD_STATE_ENUM>Dummy datas</WPRD_STATE_ENUM>
     <TReadonly>Dummy datas</TReadonly>
  </TimePeriods>
  <TimePeriods>
    <WPRD_UID>Dummy datas</WPRD_UID>
    <WPRD_START_DATE>2013-10-01T00:00:00+02:00</WPRD_START_DATE>
    <WPRD_FINISH_DATE>Dummy datas</WPRD_FINISH_DATE>
    <WPRD_NAME>Dummy datas</WPRD_NAME>
    <WPRD_STATE_ENUM>Dummy datas</WPRD_STATE_ENUM>
    <TReadonly>Dummy datas</TReadonly>
  </TimePeriods>
</TimePeriodDataSet>
```

And this code to select nodes :

```
XmlNamespaceManager mgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(contentTS.NameTable);
mgr.AddNamespace("nm", contentTS.DocumentElement.NamespaceURI);
//var nodeListTsP = contentTS.SelectNodes("//nm:TimePeriodDataSet/nm:TimePeriods", mgr);
var nodeListTsP = contentTS.SelectNodes("//nm:TimePeriodDataSet/nm:TimePeriods" + "[nm:WPRD_START_DATE >=" + bDateX + "]", mgr);
```

When I use the commented SelectNodes, it works. nodeListTsP contains 2 elements. But when I use the second, it contains nothing! (bDateX value is "2012-04-02"). Normally, the nodeList should contains the 2 elements again, no?

Do you have an explanation or a solution ?

Comment: Your addition doesn't work... I can't find what's the problem, and it's pretty important for my work, so I need help

Comment: This cannot be done with a single XPath 1.0 expression. Standard .NET libraries implement only the 1.0 standards - to use 2.0 you need to use a third-party library. Having seen the code I'd say that the easiest way is to use an XPath to get all item elements and then do the filtering using C# - i.e. get the value of the date sub-element, convert it to a date-time using DateTime.Parse and then do the comparison in C# code.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11942793/how-do-i-select-nodes-based-on-a-date-range-in-xpath

Comment: Indeed, after searching a thought it was the easiest way, so i'm trying to do that. Thank you

Comment: If you are restricted to XSLT 1.0 (as @Aleksander Kuc mentioned) the basic problem is that XPath does not define a comparison for strings which you would need in your condition. IF you want to execute the comparison in XSLT there is a pretty ugly way around this: create an XPath statement that converts the date string into an integer value and then compare this value to your parameter which needs to have been converted to an integer accordingly.

Comment: Thank you, but I get a list of all the `TimePeriods` and I did the test in C# ¨!

Comment: I think @Aleksander Kuc should convert his comment into an answer...

Comment: @T2o *instead* of XPath you can use LINQ to XML.

Answer (score 0):

This cannot be done with a single XPath 1.0 expression. Standard .NET libraries implement only the 1.0 standards - to use 2.0 you need to use a third-party library. Having seen the code I'd say that the easiest way is to use an XPath to get all item elements and then do the filtering using C# - i.e. get the value of the date sub-element, convert it to a date-time using DateTime.Parse and then do the comparison in C# code.

[How do I select nodes based on a date range in xpath?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11942793/how-do-i-select-nodes-based-on-a-date-range-in-xpath)

Answer (score 0):

.NET's built-in classes don't support XPath 2.0. An alternative is to use [LINQ to XML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/querying-xml-trees), eg :

```
var date=DateTimeOffset.Parse("2013-09-19T00:00:00+02:00");
var root=XElement.Parse(input);
XNamespace ns = "Dummy datas"; 

var periods = from period in root.Elements(ns + "TimePeriods")
              where DateTimeOffset.Parse(period.Element(ns+"WPRD_START_DATE").Value) > date
              select period;
```

Or

```
var periods = from period in root.Elements(ad + "TimePeriods")
              let dateElt=period.Element(ad+"WPRD_START_DATE")
              where DateTimeOffset.Parse(dateElt.Value) > date
              select period;
```